# Apache Spark sequential processing of text file

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a huge text file that I need to split into shingles of N characters. I have no problems, doing it the sequential way, but when it comes to parallelise my code using Spark, I experience difficulties.

The main problem is that as I've understood, DFS splits text into chunks and push it into different nodes, while w-shinging algorithms must process text as a sequence of words and surely there will be a point in algorithm cycle, where it must process words that are stored in different nodes.

The no-parallelized algorithm:

```
   StringBuffer msgsb = new StringBuffer("");
   int wordsPerShingle = 8;
   String words[] = text.split(" ");
   int total = words.length - wordsPerShingle  + 1; 
   msgs = new String[total];
   for(int i = 0; i < total; i++){
       for(int j = i; j < wordsPerShingle + i - 1; j++) {
          msgsb.append(words[j]+ " "); 
       } 
       msgsb.append(words[wordsPerShingle + i - 1]); 
       msgs[i] = new String(msgsb);
       msgsb = new StringBuffer();
    }
    return msgs;
```

The question is: Is it possible to process using Apache Spark?

Comment: .textFile will load the file as a sequence of lines (broken at linefeed boundaries). If your word sequences span a line-feed then your results will be polluted. You could write a custom InputFormat which used sentences or paragraphs for a better boundary.

Comment: @AlisterLee is it possible to force Spark don't break the files? My documents are not so big. For example, I have a dir with 1000 doc with size 0.2-5MB, is it possible to send 1 doc to one node, another to another..?

Comment: yes, it is possible with `wholeTextFiles()` function, which would result in a set of key-value pairs, where the key is filename and the value is file text

Comment: @0x0FFF I've tried this one and it works very-very slow. 1001 files (200Kb per one), `wholeTextFiles()` - 12 sec, while reading a file with 1001 paths to files and then mapping to file contents with `FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(filePath));` - 3 sec. Whats wrong?

Comment: HDFS is not designed for working with a set of small files. FYI, 12 seconds for Hadoop is not slow, it is blazing fast. If you want to have a good performance, save all your small files in a single sequencefile (key - filename, value - file text) and enable block compression in it. But in the end, you don't need a cluster to process 200MB of data